# UITableViewCell with dynamic content and dynamic row height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view similar to below. **Each question can contain dynamic no of answers and hence cell height can be changed.** I need to avoid writing manual coding as much as possible(Creating Button and labels programmatically and add to Tableview contentView) and prefer using XIB's and do everything from interface builder. Whats the best possible way to do this?

[image]

Comment: IB is best suited for static content. As you pointed out, each question has a dynamic number of answers. If you use a table cell to represent an answer, dynamic height for each cell isn't necessary (based on image above). You can still use IB to design a `UITableViewCell` subclass and the view controller that will house the table, but there is no way to avoid writing code for the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like the easiest solution would be to assign each numbered item to a section and implement each collection of options as rows. Doing this will not require dynamic heights for rows, although it may be required for sections depending on your content and desired look. Either way, the result is a trivial amount of work required to implement what you're looking for.

You can design each cell in IB like so:
[image]

Register it with the table view:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourSubclass" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

And implement the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods, as pointed out by @GoodSp33d. These methods are required to tell the table view about your dynamic content. There is no way to do this in IB alone.

Comment: totally correct as I see it but too short to help the OP as this is what GoodSp33d detailed and that didn't fly either

Comment: I've added few more details to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid programatic creation of buttons and labels. You could design the Table View as :

```
-Section 1 header view - Question 1 Title
-- Row 1 - Option 1
-- Row 2 - Option 2
-- Row 3 - Option 3 
-Section 2  header view - Question 2 Title
-- Row 1 - Option 1
-- Row 2 - Option 2
-- Row 3 - Option 3
```

... and so on

You need to create a suitable Model for this structure as well. An Array of Dictionaries would do the job.

```
NSArray *data = @[
@{@"Question_Title":@"Do you feel lucky punk ?",
  @"Options":@[@"yes", @"no"]},
]
```

And in TableView's DataSource

```
-numberOfSectionsInTableView
 return data.count

-numberOfRowsInSection
 NSDictionary *options = data.section
 NSArray *optionsArray = options[@"Options"];
 return optionsArray.count;
```

Comment: No of answers is completely dynamic. So its not feasible to design it by the IB.

Comment: + :: this doesn't propose a static layout in IB at all... why do think so?